# Why does invalid HTML work?

Tags: html

i am new to web programming but i want to ask one question: Why does invalid HTML work? why validation of html is not required?

```
<html>
<body>
</html>
```

the html file will be displayed even if it contains the syntactical error like the one mentioned above. Why is it so?

Comment: This is both too broad and off-topic; “why” questions are non-constructive and tend to spawn speculations and debate, and won’t help in programming or other coding.

Comment: @Jukka: Well to be fair, certain why questions can have primarily objective answers and thus practical value. Of course this is also provided they're specific and not overly broad.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> While browsers will attempt to display your HTML even if there are errors, there are some good reasons to validate your HTML:
>
> While the HTML may display, it may display differently than if it were written correctly.
> Errors will compound with one another. One error may display fine, two might have a slight problem, and 5-10 might cause the page to display completely incorrectly.
> While most modern browsers are forgiving, newer user agents like cell phones, PDAs and so on may not be as forgiving. Broken pages will lose you readers.
> Invalid HTML, especially if it's been deprecated, may not be supported by browsers in the future. So, while the  tag works right now, future browsers might not support it, and then your pages using that tag will no longer work.

read more here http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/f/invalid_html_ok.htm

Comment: You did not write this. http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/f/invalid_html_ok.htm

Comment: @BoltClock u r right.the post seemed helpful so i shared it here.

Comment: Yes but you have to link to the page you copied it from.

Comment: This does not address any of the questions asked.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpelawhat are you missing?

Comment: The questions were “Why does invalid HTML work?”, “why validation of html is not required?”, and why an HTML file “will be displayed even if it contains the syntactical error like the one mentioned above”. The text posted does not answer or even address a single one of them. Instead, it answers the implied and quite different question “should I validate my HTML?”

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that it's plainly market economy at work. As a regular user, you couldn't care less about HTML validation and often doesn't even know what it is. What matters is that the page look good in your browser. If one browser strictly follows the w3c standards and refuse to render pages with errors and another simply ignores the errors and renders the page as good as it can, it isn't really hard to imagine what browser people would choose.

However as other has already said, you should still try to write correct code even if it isn't always required. HTML engines change behaviour all the time, and something that may work now may not work next year. Also the more errors you have, it becomes more likely that everything will eventually just break apart.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can automatically correct invalid HTML, so page can be displayed without showing error message to user.

It is better to display something instead of error message. Most of times you can still use page if there is some error. If you display external ads, and what if that ad contains invalid HTML, then your page would just display error, because some external ad failed to provide valid HTML.

However if Strict XHTML page don't validate, then error message is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Because if a page contains errors, the browser makes his best effort to "guess" what you want. And this guess changes from browser to browser. So the page could be rendered in different ways depending on the browser you are using.